# Micropython - how to get receive data in background

Tags: python, esp8266, esp32, micropython

I am using ESP8266 (Wemos D1 mini) with MicroPython to display on OLED actual time with seconds and temperature from my local weather staion.

Fragment of code

```
try:
    while True:

        now = utime.localtime()
        hour = str(now[3])
        minu  = str(now[4])
        secs  = str(now[5])
        actualtime = hour + ":" + minu + ":" + secs

        #clear OLED and display actualtime
        oled.fill(0)
        oled.textactualtime, 0, 0)

        #every 30 seconds get data from api
        if secs == '30':
            data = get_from_api(url)

        oled.text("Temperature: "+data["temp"]+ " C", 0, 45)    
        oled.show()
        sleep(1)
```

Every minute I am trying to get actual temperature via url request.
**The problem is that this operation can take up to few seconds and then my clock is freezing not showing time with every seconds.**

How to get this kind of data in separate process / parallel process to not slowing that my loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways you could do this.

One option might be to use a `Timer` to update your oled.

https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/esp8266/quickref.html#timers

It might look like this. Please note, ***this is not working code*** as I simply copied and rearranged the code in your question:

```py
from machine import Timer
import micropython

data = None

def update_oled(_):
    now = utime.localtime()
    hour = str(now[3])
    minu  = str(now[4])
    secs  = str(now[5])
    actualtime = hour + ":" + minu + ":" + secs

    #clear OLED and display actualtime
    oled.fill(0)
    oled.textactualtime, 0, 0)

    if data != None:
        oled.text("Temperature: "+data["temp"]+ " C", 0, 45)

    oled.show()

def schedule_update_oled(_):
    micropython.schedule(update_oled, 0)

timer = Timer(-1)
timer.init(period=1000, mode=Timer.PERIODIC, callback=schedule_update_oled)

try:
    while True:
        data = get_from_api(url)
        sleep(30)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    timer.deinit()
```

Note, the timer is an interrupt so its not a good idea to have too much code in the callback. You may also need to use `schedule`.

https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/reference/isr_rules.html#using-micropython-schedule

---

Another option might be to use break up your code in to different streams:

https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/uselect.html

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help. Yout solution seems to be working as expected.
However I am getting an error when trying to stop the script:

File "<stdin>", line 118, in schedule_update_oled
NameError: name 'micropython' isn't defined

So this pointing me to this line: micropython.schedule(update_oled, 0)

Comment: Did you have the `import micropython` line and does it work? It may not be available in your port or build?

Here is a link to the doc:
https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/micropython.html

However, using `schedule` is optional and only really needed if `update_oled` is slow. So you could comment out that line and just call `update_oled()` directly.

Comment: @Reily: it is working fine, of course import micropython is in my code, only errors when trying to stop the script. Thank you for your help

Comment: @Tikky Sorry sometimes its just good to get the minor, obvious things out of the way first. I think you could maybe wrap the `while True` loop in a `try` with `except`: `timer.deinit()` which will then stop trying to call `micropython`. Just a hunch, might not work.

Comment: ... I mean `except` on `KeyboardInterrupt`